# Laravel - socket - ratchet - api authentication

Tags: laravel, sockets, authentication, authorization, ratchet

I develop a Laravel REST API  for an iOS application (being developed by another guy). This means no web-part at all, the application communicates via CURL requests to API. Though cookies are used.

Now I need to check online/offline user status, where socket comes. And I cannot understand how I can authenticate a user on a socket connect.

At all examples I've managed to find a JS script handles authentication at Laravel via PHP sessions and cookies.

So in my scenario for REST API the iOS app gets ACCESS_TOKEN which I can later use in sockets.

> A CURL request POSTs login and password and gets access token in JSON
>   format and refresh token in cookie.

```
curl -kX POST https://site/login -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -D headers.txt -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '
{
    "username":"gruzua",
    "password":"qwerty09876",
}'
```

**Response**

JSON part

```
{
    "access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "expires_in":600,
}
```

Cookie part (just in case):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Wed, 17 May 2017 17:08:09 GMT
Set-Cookie: refreshToken=SOME_REFRESH_TOKEN; expires=Mon, 07-Jan-2019 17:08:09 GMT; Max-Age=51840000; path=/; HttpOnly
```

> On each sequent request CURL sends the ACCESS_TOKEN token to
>   authenticate

`curl -kX GET https://site/user  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'`

At this point I have an access token and want to open a socket connection.

According to http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world I can open a telnet connection and write there some JSON formatted data containing my ACCESS_TOKEN. At the server side in a Ratchet ComponentInterface implementation **onOpen** method I have to check user authorization. Maybe it's not possible **onOpen**, then the options is **onMessage**? Anyway

My question is how to use laravel authentication here?

```
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later

/* 
Here I have to get somehow the user ACCESS_TOKEN
and to check authorization the way it's checked 
when using CURL passes ACCESS_TOKEN in header 
Something like this
$user = Auth::user();
if (!emtpy($user))
{
// Check e.g. user permissions (authorization) and allow connection if it's ok
}
else
{
// Reject connection
}
*/
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }
...
```

As far as I understand a client can pass a JSON string to socket connection. The server I can query my **oauth_access_tokens** laravel database for the ACCESS_TOKEN and get my user model and load the corresponding user data. But I think it's not the correct way, as I want to use all the power of Laravel guard/middleware and other coll stuff which I'm not as familiar with as I'd like, but I feel it badly needed. So I want to check authentication not by hands, but to let laravel do the job.

I'm aware of this topic [Laravel Ratchet socket Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762684/laravel-ratchet-socket-auth) , but it speaks of Session and request cookies, which is not possible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how my solution looks like.

I need this approach to authorize in a browser-less socket connection (Ratchet), where JS code is not running. So I could not use Ratchet WebSocket, only simple socket Ratchet IoServer.

My API controller returns JSON so it's easy to work with the response further.

I need this approach mainly to authenticate the socket connection assuming the client knows the access token when one opens the socket (got by REST on login).

A user connects by telnet and posts a JSON string containing the token. Alas, I didn't manage

`telnet 192.168.0.100 8080`

`{"token":"ACCESS_TOKEN"}`

The the ratchet server class looks like this described here
[Call Laravel controller from code and pass HTTP headers to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982067/call-laravel-controller-from-code-and-pass-http-headers-to-it/44988932#44988932)

So according to my API controller response (false or current user if autheticated) I can decide if the $conn is authenticated as well.

Here is another narrower question, helping with this question answer: [Call Laravel controller from code and pass HTTP headers to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982067/call-laravel-controller-from-code-and-pass-http-headers-to-it)